# ctags navigate to java static methods in vim

Tags: vim, ctags

There are execute static methods in every class file in java.

When I do *Ctrl+]*, it goes to current class method. To go to another class execute method, I have to do *:ts* and navigate there.

How can I automatically go to the other class's static execute method using ctags in vim?

The only thing I have done while building ctags is the following:
*ctags --language-force=java -R **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. `<C-]>` jumps you to the first occurrence of the word under the cursor in your `tags` file.

Vim itself has no mechanism to guess what method you want to jump to or infer scope from context and not much information can be gleaned from your `tags` file to make that feature smarter anyway.

You can use `g<C-]>` (same behavior as `:ts`) or `g]` (same behavior as `:tj`) as alternatives to `<C-]>`.